# search and replace with 'jq' JSON shell tool

Tags: mongodb, search, replace, sed, jq

Here extract from JSON output. The JSON document automationConfig is MongoDB Ops Manager, a commercial product for management of `mongod`.

```
$ cat automationConfig |  jq '.processes[]'
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28200
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_0",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_0/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-ca-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-1.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace_0",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28200
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_1",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_1/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-ca-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-2.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace_1",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28200
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_2",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-cache-dbspace/wooomtest-cache-dbspace_2/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-ca-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-3.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-cache-dbspace_2",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28000
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_3",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_3/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-id-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-1.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace_3",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28000
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_4",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_4/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-id-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-2.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace_4",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28000
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_5",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-identity-dbspace/wooomtest-identity-dbspace_5/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-id-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-3.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-identity-dbspace_5",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28300
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-library-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_6",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_6/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-lib-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-1.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-library-dbspace_6",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28300
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-library-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_7",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_7/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-lib-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-2.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-library-dbspace_7",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28300
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-library-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_8",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-library-dbspace/wooomtest-library-dbspace_8/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-lib-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-3.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-library-dbspace_8",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28100
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_9",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_9/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-st-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-1.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace_9",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28100
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_10",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_10/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-st-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-2.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace_10",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28100
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_11",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-storage-dbspace/wooomtest-storage-dbspace_11/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "disabled": false,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-st-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-3.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-storage-dbspace_11",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28400
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-support-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_12",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_12/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-sup-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-1.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-support-dbspace_12",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28400
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-support-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_13",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_13/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-sup-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-2.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-support-dbspace_13",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
{
  "args2_6": {
    "net": {
      "port": 28400
    },
    "operationProfiling": {},
    "replication": {
      "replSetName": "wooomtest-support-dbspace"
    },
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_14",
      "engine": "wiredTiger"
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "path": "/data/wooomtest-support-dbspace/wooomtest-support-dbspace_14/mongodb.log"
    }
  },
  "authSchemaVersion": 5,
  "hostname": "node-z5-wooomtest-sup-sc-wooom-stack4-prd-3.sc-wooom-stack4-prd.local",
  "logRotate": {
    "sizeThresholdMB": 1000,
    "timeThresholdHrs": 24
  },
  "name": "wooomtest-support-dbspace_14",
  "processType": "mongod",
  "version": "3.0.7"
}
```

I was able to extract only version

```
$ cat automationConfig |  jq '.processes[] .version' 
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
"3.0.7"
```

Now I wish to replace the number "3.0.7" with "3.0.6" using shell tool `jq`.

I am following this [docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/update-mongodb-version-of-deployment-via-api/), but wish to do downgrade (not upgrade).

Comment: `cat automationConfig | jq '.processes[].version = "3.0.6"'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've extracted the values you need, it's just a matter of assigning them a new value.

```
$ cat automationConfig | jq '.processes[].version = "3.0.6"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for the processes that has the versions you want to update, then update them.

```
(.processes[] | select(.version == "3.0.7")).version = "3.0.6"
```